# Use Swagger/OpenAPI discriminator so that Jackson serializes object correctly

Tags: jackson, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi

We're having trouble using the OpenAPI 2.0 discriminator in way that makes both the Swagger tools and the Jackson serializer happy.

Problem: during serialization Jackson currently generates two JSON properties for the discriminator, one of them having a `null` value.

**OpenAPI 2.0 definition**

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: v1
  title: Error API
paths:
  /errors:
    get:
      description: Stack Overflow test
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/SpecificError'
definitions:
  GeneralError:
    description: Error Base Structure
    type: object
    discriminator: errorType
    properties:
      errorType:
        type: string
      message:
        type: string
    required: 
      - errorType
  SpecificError:
    description: Test
    allOf: 
      - $ref: "#/definitions/GeneralError"
```

AFAIU the discriminator is correctly defined. [The spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-13) requires it to be listed both in the `properties` and the `required` list.

> The property name used MUST be defined at this schema and it MUST be in the required property list. When used, the value MUST be the name of this schema or any schema that inherits it.

**Swagger codegen**

What the Swagger Java codegen produces is this:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "errorType",
    visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SpecificError.class, name = "SpecificError"),
})

public class GeneralError {
    @JsonProperty("errorType")
    private String errorType = null;
    // accessors, even for errorType!, follow here
```

The accessors for `errorType` come as a big surprise. As the field is only needed during serialization & deserialization regular client code shouldn't have access to it. One could even argue that the field shouldn't be there at all.

**Jackson serializer**

As a simple test bed I use this

```java
SpecificError specificError = (SpecificError) new SpecificError().message("message")
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.writer();
writer.writeValue(System.out, specificError);
```

This produces `{"errorType":"SpecificError","message":"message","errorType":null}`.

-> `errorType` appears twice

Q: whose fault is it? Is my Swagger definition wrong? Should the Swagger Java codegen not generate `private String errorType`? Or should Jackson be able to deal with this i.e. recognize that its `@JsonTypeInfo` and the property of that name are actually the same thing?

Comment: Follow-up 1: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8137. Follow-up 2: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2022

Comment: I've had the same issue and came to the same conclusions, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706241/why-discriminator-property-gets-serialized-twice. I've even opened an issue on the main repo https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3796,